# SQL 2005 CSV Import Quote Delimited with inner Quotes and Commas

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, csv, import

I have a CSV file with quote text delimiters.  Most of the 90000 rows are fine, but I have a few rows that have a text field that contains both a quote and a comma.  For example the fields value would be:

> AB",AB

When Delimited this becomes

> "AB"",AB"

When SQL 2005 attempts to import this I get errors such as...

```
Messages
Error 0xc0202055: Data Flow Task: The column delimiter for column "Column 4" was not found.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

This only seems to happen when a quote and comma are in a text value together.  Values like

AB"AB which becomes "AB""AB"
or
AB,AB which becomes "AB,AB"

work fine.

Here are some example rows...

```
"1464885","LEVER WM","","B","MP17"
"1465075",":PLT-BC   !!NOTE!!","","B",""
"1465076","BRKT-STR MTR            !NOTE!","","B",""
"1465172",":BRKT-SW MTG   !NOTE!","","B","MP16"
"1465388","BUSS BAR                !NOTE!","","B","MP10"
"1465391","PLT-BLKHD     ""NOTE""","","B","MP20"
"1465564","SPROCKET:13TEETH,74MM OD,66MM","ID W/.25"" SETSCR","B","MP6"
"S01266330002","CABLE:224"",E122/261,8 CO","","B","MP11"
```

The last row is an example of the problem - the "", causes the error.

Answer (score 4):

I've had MAJOR problems with SSIS.  Things that Access, Excel and even DTS seemed to do very well, SSIS chokes on.  Variable record-length data is another problem but, yes, these embedded qualifiers are a major problem.  Especially if you do not have access to the import files because they're on someone else's server that you pay to gain access to and might even be 4 to 5 GB in size!  Cant just to a "replace all" on that every import.

You may want to check into this at Microsoft Downloads called "[UnDouble](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=B51463E9-2907-4B82-A353-E15016486E1D)"  and here is another [workaround](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/f1502bec-17fa-4bf1-8c5d-b8d24b16218e/) you might try.

Seems like with SSIS in SQL Server 2008, the bug is still there.  I dont know why they havent addressed this in the parser but its like we went back in time with SSIS in basic import functionality.

**UPDATE 11-18-2010:**  This bug still exists in SSIS.  Amazing.

Answer (score 1):

How about just:

1. Search/replace all "", with ''; (fix all the broken fields)
2. Search/replace all ;''; with ,"", (to "unfix" properly empty fields.)
3. Search/replace all '';''; with "","", (to "unfix" properly empty fields which follow a correct encapsulation of embedded delimiters.)

That converts your original to:

```
   "1464885","LEVER WM","","B","MP17"
"1465075",":PLT-BC   !!NOTE!!","","B",""
"1465076","BRKT-STR MTR            !NOTE!","","B",""
"1465172",":BRKT-SW MTG   !NOTE!","","B","MP16"
"1465388","BUSS BAR                !NOTE!","","B","MP10"
"1465391","PLT-BLKHD     ""NOTE""","","B","MP20"
"1465564","SPROCKET:13TEETH,74MM OD,66MM","ID W/.25"" SETSCR","B","MP6"
"S01266330002","CABLE:224'';E122/261,8 CO","","B","MP11"
```

Which seems to run the gauntlet fine in SSIS. You may have to step 3 recursively to account for 3 empty fields in a row ('';'';'';, etc.) but the bottom line here is that when you have embedded text qualifiers, you have to either escape them or replace them. Let this be a lesson in your CSV creation processes going forward.

Comment: In another comment, the OP says he only has access to the import file,  not the CSV creation. Also, your answer changes the data (double-quotes to single-quotes); so this isn't really solving the problem of how to import this data.

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft says](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=312164) doubled double quotes inside double quote delimited fields just don't work. A fix is planned for the end of 2011...

In the mean time we will have to use workarounds like described in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I would just do a search/replace for ", and replace it with ,

Do you have access to the original file?

Comment: No I have access to the import file only. 
Also the file is full of ", or "", that are valid.
Here are some example rows...
"1465564","SPROCKET:13TEETH,74MM OD,66MM","ID W/.25"" SETSCR","B","MP6"
"S01266330002","CABLE:224"",E122/261,8 CO","","B","MP11"

2nd row is